# Get property values from another view model when its window closes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a view model which has a command in it that shows a new window (that has it's own view model). The new window's view model has various properties, and when I close the new window, I want to pass those properties back to the first view model that called it.

I'm breaking the MVVM pattern here since it just seemed quicker and easier to show the new window with `ShowDialog()`. Here's an example of my code:

MainViewModel:

```
//Note: The OnPropertyChanged and CanExecute functions are implemented

//method via command to show a new window
private void ShowSYOWindow(object parameter)
{
    SYOWindow syo = new SYOWindow();
    syo.ShowDialog();
}
```

New window's view model:

```
class SYOWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       

    private DateTime _timeStart;
    public DateTime TimeStart
    {
        get { return _timeStart; }
        set { _timeStart = value; OnPropertyChanged("TimeStart"); }
    }

    private DateTime _timeStart2;
    public DateTime TimeStart2
    {
        get { return _timeStart2; }
        set { _timeStart2 = value; OnPropertyChanged("TimeStart2"); }
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code-behind for the SYOWindow:

```
using Proj1.ViewModels; //viewmodel located in different folder in project
public partial class SYOWindow : Window
{
    public SYOWindowViewModel vm => (SYOWindowViewModel)DataContext; //error here

    public SYOWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OKBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = true;
    }

    private void CancelBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = false;
    }
}
```

So after I open the new window with 'syo.ShowDialog()' from the MainViewModel, and I set some properties in the SYOWindowViewModel for the syo Window, I want to return those properties to the MainViewModel. I can't figure out what the 'proper' and cleanest way to do this is. I've read that I can cast the DataContext and then get the values that way, but that seems kind of wrong. But maybe the only way since I broke the MVVM using the showdialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShowDialog()` blocks, so you can just have the parent take stuff from the child's viewmodel after `ShowDialog()` exits:

```
private void ShowSYOWindow(object parameter)
{
    SYOWindow syo = new SYOWindow();
    syo.ShowDialog();

    var vm = (SYOWindowViewModel)syo.DataContext;

    this.Foo = vm.Foo;
}
```

You can simplify the code a bit if you give `SYOWindow` a `ViewModel` property:

```
public partial class SYOWindow : Window
{
    //  ...stuff

    //  C#6 version -- but if you're on an earlier version of C#, you'll get 
    //  "DataContext is a property but is used like a type" and a red squiggly.
    //public SYOWindowViewModel ViewModel => (SYOWindowViewModel)DataContext;

    //  C#<=5. This works fine in C#6 as well.
    public SYOWindowViewModel vm { get { return (SYOWindowViewModel)DataContext; } }

    //  ...more stuff
 }
```

Then the parent can just do like so:

```
private void ShowSYOWindow(object parameter)
{
    SYOWindow syo = new SYOWindow();

    syo.ShowDialog();

    this.Foo = syo.ViewModel.Foo;
}
```

And if `SYOWindow` uses [its `DialogResult` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx), you can do stuff like this:

```
private void ShowSYOWindow(object parameter)
{
    SYOWindow syo = new SYOWindow();

    if (syo.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
    {
        this.Foo = syo.ViewModel.Foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just wondering, how does the second snippet of code you posted simplify code by giving the window a viewmodel property?

Comment: Oh never mind I see now. Thanks for the suggestion! Going to look into the dialogresult property as well.

Comment: Couldn't get `public SYOWindowViewModel ViewModel => (SYOWindowViewModel)DataContext;` to work properly. Says DataContext can't be used as a type.

Comment: If `SYOWindow` is a subclass of Window (I forgot the ` : Window` part in my answer, sorry), that should be fine as a property of `SYOWindow`. It sounds like you're defining that as a property of a viewmodel or something else that doesn't have a `DataContext` property.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason it's showing `syo.ViewModel.Foo` as null when going back to the MainViewModel. The line you posts still doesn't work, so I tried initializing it the constructor instead, but it's still null for some reason.

Comment: None of that makes any sense to me because I haven't seen your code. You're initializing what in which class's constructor, and how are you initializing it? What does "going back to the MainViewModel" mean?

Comment: The line `public SYOWindowViewModel ViewModel => (SYOWindowViewModel)DataContext;` still gives the error `DataContext is a property but is used like a type`. I put this in my SYOWindow.xaml.cs file. When I say back to the mainviewmodel I just mean back to the function that called the ShowDialog. Sorry about that.

Comment: I need to see the C# code for SYOWindow. Everything in SYOWindow.xaml.cs. Please paste it into your question.

Comment: Done. Only thing I didn't put is all the other `using` statements which are just the basics.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I gave you C#6 code but I think you might be on C#5. Try this for that line instead: `public SYOWindowViewModel vm { get { return (SYOWindowViewModel)DataContext; } }`

Comment: Yup that was it! Haha. Sorry about that, was gonna say I never used the lambda operator for this before. Thanks again!

Comment: @pfinferno Awesome. Sorry about all the trouble!

Answer (score 1):

`ShowDialog();` blocks execution until the dialog is closed, so all you need to do is:

```
form.ShowDialog();
var myVar = form.myVar;
```